# css not applied for 1st time but applies 2nd time onwards

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I want to change color of a text in html when ajax response is successful.
Below is a code :

I get `data.req_id` correctly from successful response of ajax
`total_reqs` is already declared as Number type.

```
var count = Number(total_reqs - data.req_id + 1);
var child = "#req_ids  p:nth-child(" + count +")";
$(child).css('color','red');
```

`$(child).css('color','red');` is not applied for 1st time but is applied every other time whenever I refresh page.

Comment: where you writing these code.? make sure that the DOM is loaded first

Comment: "Because jQuery's implementation of :nth- selectors is strictly derived from the CSS specification, the value of n is "1-indexed", meaning that the counting starts at 1" ....are you sure your first number is not "0"? If your first number is 0, that selector will fail, the second would find an element because it would be a 1. But honestly, youll have to give us the values for `total_reqs` and `data.req_id` for anyone to be sure what is wrong

Comment: What value is the count variable holding? Make sure it is what you are expecting.

Comment: what's the first value of your count?

Comment: value of count is correct.. If there is any problem in count then property wont be applied for second time.

Comment: var total_reqs = $("#req_ids p").length; and data.req_id = 5 .. value of total_reqs > 5.. I checked it by putting an alert.

Comment: can you 'manually' select the element from console? $('#req_ids p:nth-child(5)')

Comment: yes.. I am able to select all elements from console.

Comment: Fixed.. There was some syntax error in html file which was basically causing issue. Sorry for trouble guys.. Appreciate your efforts !

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.. There was some syntax error in html file which was basically causing issue. Sorry for trouble guys.. Appreciate your efforts ! –